# Using Resource Governor to Limit Second SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-administration, resource-governor

Trying to get a handle on Resource Governor for SQL Server 2012.

I have a dev box with the following instances:

[Server Instances http://hardhobbittobreak.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/server-instances.png](http://hardhobbittobreak.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/server-instances.png)

I want to set up Resource Governor so that the Tabular SSAS instance only gets 20% of the server's CPU and RAM. Is that possible? And if so, how? The information I've researched so far doesn't help me as much as I'd hoped it would.

Bonus prize: best answer from someone going to TechNet next week in Houston gets a beer. :p

Comment: Looking at that, I see I need to patch the tabular instance. Doh.

Comment: It's not letting me multi-select correct answers, so I'm deadlocking and giving the priority to MBourgon, because his answer gave a solution to the issue, which was more what I needed, though I think Robert deserved some credit too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set it there - in SSMS, open the AS instance, then right-click and go to properties.  You want to set the HardMemoryLimit/LowMemoryLimit/TotalMemoryLimit/VertipaqMemoryLimit properties.

It's percentages of TOTAL RAM ON THE BOX.  So if you're running multiple instances (like classic and tabular), you need to share it between them.  And you'll need to cap the SQL Server instance as well.

Comment: Granting this 1/2 of the answer, correctly answering the negative of "If so, how?" -- since the answer was no, he answered "If not, how?". 

Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Woohoo! Not the deadlock victim for once!

Answer (score 1):

Resource Governor only works on the database engine. It cannot be used for Analysis Services. See the Resource Governor Constraints section here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895232%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Instead, you may want to look at Windows System Resource Manager (WSRM): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755056.aspx

Comment: Granting this 1/2 of the answer, correctly answering the "Is this possible" question with "You can't."